# Is there a way to operate a tkinter GUI via script?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to speed test my code for a tkinter GUI. Naturally, requiring humans to hit buttons would make speed testing inconsistent. I was thinking that I could just have a timed script run each callback sequentially, but some callbacks like image displays wouldn't be able to run without the GUI open. Now I'm looking for ways to run a script on a GUI that's already in its main loop. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a few modules for handling GUI automation but here is a pretty nice tutorial https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/.

Also with windows you should be able to simulate keystrokes and mouse movements using the win32 api https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/.